# react_devtools_backend.js:4012 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs

//========================================

## 1. component App:

```
function App() {

//created cont with objects for creating guest's cards

    const [guess, setGuess] = useState([
        {id: 1, number: 1, name: "Maks", age: 27, city: "Krasnodar", partner: "with wife", phone: +79292642644,country: "Russia"},
        // {id: 2, number: 2, name: "Dmitriy", age: 30, city: "Moscow", partner: "with wife", phone: +79293647821,country: "Russia"},
    ]);


// function for changing guess, and add new person

    const createNewGuess = (newGuess) => {
        setGuess([...guess, newGuess])
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <FormAddGuest add = {createNewGuess}/>
        <MyTest guess = {guess} title = "СПИСОК ГОСТЕЙ"/>
      </div>
  )
}
```

//========================================

## component MyTest:

```
//creating guest's cards with key = item.id

const MyTest = ({guess, title}) => {
    // console.log(guess)
    return (
        <div className="basic">
            <div className="basic__container">
                <div className="basic__block">
                <div className="basic__title">{title}</div>
                    {guess.map(item => {
                        // console.log(item)
                            return <Guess about = {item} key = {item.id}/>
                        }
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

//========================================

## and last component FormAddGuest:

```
const FromAddGuest = function ({add}) {
   
    const [value, setValue] = useState({ number: '', name: '', age: '', city: '', partner: '',phone: '', country: ''});


// function after click on button

    let addGuests = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const newGuess = {
            id:Date.now(),
            ...value,
        }
        console.log(newGuess) //here i see every element numver,name... after i've wrote information and cliked button

        add({newGuess})
        setValue({number: '', name: '', age: '', city: '', partner: '',phone: '', country: ''})
    }

    return (
        <form className="form-main" action="">
            <div className="form-main__container">
                <div className="form-main__title">Карточка гостя</div>
                <div className="form-main__for-inp">
                <MyInput
                    value ={value.number}
                    onChange ={e => setValue({...value,number: e.target.value})}
                />
                <MyInput
                    value = {value.name}
                    onChange = {e => setValue({...value, name: e.target.value})}
                />
                <MyInput
                    value = {value.age}
                    onChange = {e => setValue({...value, age: e.target.value})}
                />
                <MyInput
                    value = {value.city}
                    onChange = {e => setValue({...value, city: e.target.value})}
                />
                <MyInput
                    value = {value.partner}
                    onChange = {e => setValue({...value, partner: e.target.value})}
                />
                <MyInput
                    value = {value.phone}
                    onChange = {e => setValue({...value, phone: e.target.value})}
                />
                <MyInput
                    value = {value.country}
                    onChange = {e => setValue({...value, country: e.target.value})}
                />
                </div>
                <MyButtonTwo onClick = {addGuests} text ="Добавить гостя" type="submit"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    )
}
```

after i've wrote information and clicked button "add guest" i see empty block and that "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."
But i wrote that key = id and id = Date.now() for new person.
i was trying to decided this problem, but i've not done it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your App component you need two changes:

```
const createNewGuess = (newGuess) => {
        setGuess(prev=>[...prev,newGuess])
    } 
<FormAddGuest add = {()=> createNewGuess(newGuess)}/>
```

and in FormAddGuest you need to change your add function to this:

```
add(newGuess)
```

you can check more about sharing states and lifting state up (which you are doing right now ) here :

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-lifting-state-up-in-react/

Comment: I changed only here:                                                                                              
          ```   add(newGuess)   ```                                                                                                         
           and it's workung..Thanks

Comment: @МаксимДмитриевич don't mention it mate